# How To Set Addapted PassData Between Activities?

Tags: xamarin.android, buttonclick, pass-data, dynamic-list

i am trying to create a dynamic list of buttons and every button create a passed data to another activity that show the relative buttons detile.

the code i used is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {

                temp = new Button(this);

                temp.SetText(data[i].Name, TextView.BufferType.Normal); //arbitrary task
                numArrey[i] = i;

                main_linearScroller.AddView(temp);

                tv[i] = temp;
                tv[i].SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Dip, 20);
                tv[i].SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.textbox_back1);
                Display d = WindowManager.DefaultDisplay;
                int width = d.Width;
                int height = d.Height;
                tv[i].SetHeight(10);
                tv[i].SetWidth(width);

                tv[i].Click += (sender,e)=>
                {
                    var detileListShow = new Intent(this, typeof(DetileListShow));
                    detileListShow.PutExtra("Data", i);
                    Console.WriteLine("Starting Activity With Data{0}", i);
                    StartActivity(detileListShow);
                };
```

every thing is good untile last parag that i setting tv[i].click.
every buttons.PutExtera = 21.
how can i fix it?
i think it's better every buttons can save the value that need to return but i dont know how...